# How to do a hexadecimal multiplication in OCaml?

Tags: hex, ocaml, multiplication

How should I do a hexademical calculation in OCaml?
For example I want to multiply 0x0a and 0xff.

What should I do?

Comment: The multiplication is not in hexadecimal. You may want to input the operands in hexadecimal, and/or to print the result in hexadecimal, and you need to multiply, of course, with integer multiplication. Which one(s) of these three are causing you trouble?

Answer (score 2):

`0x0a * 0xff`

Hexadecimal is just yet another notation, not another algebra.

Answer (score 2):

For the whole package, use `Printf.printf "%x\n" (0x0a * 0xff)`.

The `%x` conversion prints in hexadecimal, and integer constants in the program can be typed in hexadecimal with the `0x` prefix.

Example:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# Printf.printf "0x%x\n" (0x0a * 0xff);;
0x9f6
```

Comment: And if you are in for a long session with hexadecimals you may want to replace the default printer for ints with `let pp_hex ppf i = Format.fprintf ppf "0x%X" i;; #install_printer pp_hex;;`